# Getting the Last Modified Date of an assembly in the GAC

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, gac

I have implemented the fusion.dll wrapper mentioned in many posts and now find that at least one dll I need to determine if it needs to be updated is not using build and revision numbers. Consequently I cannot compare on version numbers and need to compare on Last Modified date.

fusion.dll or it's wrappers have no such method which I guess is fair enough but how do I determine the 'real' path of the dll so that I can discovers it's last Modified date.

My code so far:

```
private DateTime getGACVersionLastModified(string DLLName)
{
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(DLLName);
  string dllName = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, "");

  DateTime versionDT = new DateTime(1960,01,01);

  IAssemblyEnum ae = AssemblyCache.CreateGACEnum();
  IAssemblyName an;
  AssemblyName name;
  while (AssemblyCache.GetNextAssembly(ae, out an) == 0)
  {
    try
    {
      name = GetAssemblyName(an);

      if (string.Compare(name.Name, dllName, true) == 0)
      {
        FileInfo dllfi = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}.dll", name.Name));
        if (DateTime.Compare(dllfi.LastWriteTime, versionDT) >= 0)
          versionDT = dllfi.LastWriteTime;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      logger.FatalException("Unable to get version number: ", ex);
    }
  }
  return versionDT;
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I played with the Fusion APIs. But have you tried calling IAssemblyCache.QueryAssemblyInfo instead? It should return, among other things, a file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem description in your question I can see there are really 2 primary tasks that you are trying to accomplish:

1) Determine if a given assembly name can be loaded from the GAC.
2) Return the file modified date for the given assembly.

I believe these 2 points can be accomplished in a much simpler fashion and without having to work with the [unmanaged fusion API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523.aspx).  An easier way to go about this task might be as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Run the method with a few test values
  GetAssemblyDetail("System.Data"); // This should be in the GAC
  GetAssemblyDetail("YourAssemblyName");  // This might be in the GAC
  GetAssemblyDetail("ImaginaryAssembly"); // This just plain doesn't exist
}

private static DateTime? GetAssemblyDetail(string assemblyName)
{
  Assembly a;
  a = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(assemblyName);
  if (a != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is in GAC? {1}", assemblyName, a.GlobalAssemblyCache);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(a.Location);
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' Modified: {1}", assemblyName, fi.LastWriteTime);
    return fi.LastWriteTime;
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Assembly '{0}' not found", assemblyName);
    return null;
  }
}
```

An example of the resulting output:

> 'System.Data' is in GAC? True
>   'System.Data' Modified: 10/1/2010 9:32:27 AM
>   'YourAssemblyName' is in GAC? False
>   'YourAssemblyName' Modified: 12/30/2010 4:25:08 AM
>   Assembly 'ImaginaryAssembly' not found

Comment: The GAC COM APIs are not undocumented. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404523.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation for the fusion API, Mattias.  I wasn't aware of this and have updated my answer summary to reflect that it is, in fact, documented.

Comment: David, Trying to compare multiple versions is a more complex problem I suppose.  If you modify the code above use Assembly.Load(AssemblyName) instead of LoadWithPartialName and use the strong name of the assembly you may be able to compare versions (I have not tested this).  This assumes that you know the strong names of the multiple versions.  Otherwise, LoadWithPartialName loads the "highest version number" according to MSDN... in your situation I don't know what this might do considering that your assembly does not use the build and revision numbers.